# magento extension to integrate with blue dart shipping company

Tags: shipping

we integrated with blue dart shipping company.

we want to know how to create labels, how to track the location for bluedart.

is there any extension which supports this kind of functionality

please help me to find solution.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There the list of extension:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/12232/

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/blue-dart-shipping-integration.html

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/blue-dart-shipping-integration.html di you used this extension before? or do you have some sample blue dart company demo label images....

Comment: yes.used 1st one

Comment: hi, what you did for getting blue dart labels?

Comment: means from 1st extension, we can get only tracking locations, am i right?

we need to get some labels, for that one we have to go with second extension only or is there any other extension?